# Determining line equation

Tags: vector-spaces

Find the equation of the line going through the point $(2,-3,4)$ ,and which is perpendicular to the plane $ x+2y + 2z = 13$

So I tried this: the normal of the plane is $(1,2,2)$, random point on the line is $(x,y,z)$, so direction vector is $(x-2,y+3,z-4)$. We'll require $(x-2,y+3,z-4)\cdot (1,2,2) = 0$. This yields $x-2y+2z -4 =0$

let us take $z=y=1$. that makes $x=0$ and so $(0,1,1)$ is a random point on the plane; and so we get direction vector $(-2,4,-3)$. This gives a line equation of: $(2,-3,4) + t(-2,4,-3)$ ;

is this right?

Comment: Shouldn't the line equation be $(2,-3,4)+t(1,2,2)$ ?

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: Because the direction of the line should be $(1,2,2)$, the normal vector of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you said that the line must be perpendicular to the normal of the plane instead of the plane itself:

$(x-2,y+3,z-4)\cdot (1,2,2)=0$ is the equation needed for the direction vector to be perpendicular to the normal, not the plane!

Comment: could you develop your line of reasoning a bit more?

Comment: Well, a vector $\vec a$ is perpendicular to a vector $\vec n$ if $\vec a\cdot \vec n = 0$, don't you agree?

Comment: that's correct..

Comment: Well then, the formula $(x-2,y+3,z-4)\cdot (1,2,2)=0$, by that logic, determines when the vector $(x-2,y+3,z-4)$ is perpendicular to $(1,2,2)$, and since $(1,2,2)$ is the normal, it means that it is perpendicular to the normal.

Comment: actually all this (my calculations) are quite redundant, as I now see, since this is an instant result after you determine the planes normal..

Comment: That is what I was trying to guide you into. Being perpendicular to the plane is equivalent to being colinear with the normal.

Comment: an important result, Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome. Just one more comment: The equation you got was actually an equation for a line that is perpendicular to the normal to the plane, meaning it was paralel to the plane.

Comment: yeah, total nonsense when referring to what was being asked in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Note that the inproduct of $(1,2,2)$ and vectors in plane $x+2y+2z=0$ is $0$. This shows that $(1,2,2)$ and this plane are perpendicular. This is also true for the parallel plane $x+2y+2z=13$. So the equation of the line must have the form $v+t(1,2,2)$. You can take $v=(2,-3,4)$ to make sure that the line contains that point.